# Angular & Javascript: Date is 7 days old and is monday

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a angular app which is connected to a rest api. To reduce the requests i save all data in the localstorage.

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
        var object = {value: value, timestamp: new Date().getTime()}
        $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(valueWithTimestamp);
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
        var object = {value: value, timestamp: new Date().getTime()}
        $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(object);
    },
  }
}]);
```

There will be new data every monday, so all i want to do is to check if the localstorage is 7 days old and if the current weekday is monday.

Then the data should refresh. Do you have any idea how to solve this simple problem?

Comment: You will probably need to store some kind of timestamp along your actual data and then compare it to the current date to see if it needs an update. So, your provider could return a promise by default that is either serving things from cache or (re-)fetching them from server (and putting it to cache again).

Comment: If `new Date().getDay() == 1` then it's Monday for the host system. If `(object.timestamp - new Date()) > 6.048e8` then it was more than 7 days ago. However, the logic `if Monday and more than 7 days ago` may not update each week if the user visits after more than a week but not on a Monday.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like its better so set a expire date and then check for date? I think its make things much more easy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is my function. Should work now :)

```
function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek) {
        // Code to check that date and dayOfWeek are valid left as an exercise ;)
        var resultDate = new Date(date.getTime());
        if (date.getDay() === 1 && dayOfWeek === 1) {
          resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 7)
        }
        else {
          resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
        }
        return resultDate;
    }
```

Comment: Please do credit your sources: [Find next occurring Friday (or any dayOfWeek)](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33532)